# update table column without reseting the database migrate Laravel

Tags: laravel, migration

I want to add new column or delete column to a table in laravel migration and I don't want to reset the database because it delete all old data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

make a new migration then the code should be like

```
Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->string('name', 50)->nullable()->change();
});
```

or if you want to rename

```
Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->renameColumn('from', 'to');
});
```

or if dropping

```
Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->dropColumn(['votes', 'avatar', 'location']);
});
```

to add simply

```
Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->string('email');
});
```

Comment: @RobinChoffardet that would drop the table .. he meant to drop the field ..

Comment: Always a bit frustrating when you were writing a entire complete answer and someone published his a few seconds before :p

Comment: @RobinChoffardet that always happens a lot to me too .. i feel you

Comment: Demonyowh : yup i know, but i saw your edited answer before his question, so i was thinking he wanted to drop the table

Comment: @Demonyowh you forget to code about adding new column? I don't want to edit . just want to add new column